# To the last degree-what is the meaning of this phrase?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is the sentence from Daniel Defoe's "Robinson Crusoe": '... raisins, which were healthful and refreshing ***to the last degree***. I guess what it could mean, but can anyone tell me the meaning of this sentence literally? thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

It is a superlative. So it means

> ... raisins, which were healthful and refreshing to the greatest extent possible.

or (as a more simple superlative)

> ... raisins, which were the most healthful and refreshing.